# How can I change the compile version to api 23 android in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, api

I'm finishing my project and need to improve compile version of eclipse to android api 23 (marshmallow).
 How can I keeping minSdkVersion to 11 and targetSdkVersion to 16, but compile my app with api 23 in eclipse??
 I mean, want to keep mini sdk lower, to support many of devices and avoid some errors of compile time cause of using api less 23, too ! for example, eclipse gives error with these methods belongs check permission to use camera (in android6) that Related of api 23:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

I updated android.support.v4.jar file more time and cleaned project and also my eclipse does not know (M) and (checkSelfPermission)!
thanks a lot !

Comment: Official support for Eclipse as an Android app development IDE ended months ago. IIRC, Project Properties > Android gives you the list of available SDK versions to compile against.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project. Then go to Properties->Android 
and select the "Project Build Target" that you want. The version you select here is used only for building and can be different than the min and target SDKs that you specify in the Manifest.